# How much data can be stored using Parse?

Tags: swift, xcode, networking, parse-platform

I am thinking about coding an application that allows users to create profiles and navigate to other profiles.

I notice that Google Firebase has a free limit of about 1 GB along with some other limits. Realm seems to have something similar for storage.

How much could I possibly store for free using Parse? I believe you can store online and offline using Parse. I don't think it would be possible for other profiles to access data stored locally on another profile. Is that right?

I do not know much about Parse even after trying to Google the limits for data storage.

Answer (score 2):

Parse is an open-source suite and you can host Parse Server in your self-hosted servers or in a Parse Server BaaS provider, such as [Back4App](https://www.back4app.com).

In the case of self-hosting, the limit are the ones of your server hosting provider.

In the case of Back4App, there is a 250M limit for database and 1GB limit for file storage in the free plan.